# Create a dictionary of the list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary whose values are lists. For example:

```
"data": {"1": {"id": 1,
               "name": test1,
               "description":yyyyy},
         "2": {"id": 2,
               "name": test2,
               "description":xxxxx}}
```

When I do this, it just creates in the list - `[]` but I want to get all the values in the list as dictionary - `{}`:

```
data = []
for x in Test.objects.filter(act=True):
    data.append({"%s" % x.id:{"id":"%s" % x.id, "name": "%s" % x.name, "description": "%s" % x.description})
ins = {}
ins['instance'] = data
```

**Result:**

```
"data": [{"1": {"id": 1,
                "name": test1,
                "description":yyyyy}},
         {"2": {"id": 2,
                "name": test2,
                "description":xxxxx}}]
```

Comment: Your example does not seam correct as the values are not lists.

Comment: where is the list?

Comment: okay. I am new in this...I thought i had to pass as list. Can you help me get the result as show in the example?

Comment: do i have to add as map object in place of using the list?

Comment: Your question is unclear about what input data you have and what output data you want?? Could you explain that properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't show any lists in your question. What you have there in your desired example is a dictionary whose values are also a dictionary. Brackets `[]` denote lists. Braces `{}` denote dictionaries. Lists are an ordered array of items. Dictionaries store values in `key:value` pairs.

Second, there's really no point to making a dictionary with keys numbered serially like that.You could simply have a list of dictionaries and refer to each item by the list index instead.

You should also name your variables for what they are rather than just `x` or `test1` or `yyyyy`.

So as for your question, it sounds like you have some values like `[1,test1,yyyyy]` or say `[x.id,x.name,x.description]` where each item corresponds in order to: `id`,`name`, and `description` I believe the way you want to sort this data is as such:

```
data=[
    {"id":1,"name":test1,"description":yyyyy},
    {"id":2,"name":test2,"description":xxxxx}
]
```

So your code might look something like

```
data=[]
for x in Test.objects.filter(act=True):
    data.append({"id":x.id,"name":x.name,"description":x.description})

#Or as a list comprehension:
#data=[{"id":x.id,"name":x.name,"description":x.description} for x in Test.objects.filter(act=True)]
```

Then you can access your data like such

```
for item in data:
    print("""\
ITEM ID: {}
ITEM NAME: {}
ITEM DESCRIPTION: {}
---------------------""".format(item["id"],item["name"],item["description"]))
```

If you REALLY wanted to format your data exactly how you described in your post:

```
the_dict={}
for index, x in enumerate(Test.objects.filter(act=True)): #assuming this is a list of objects
    the_dict[str(index+1)]={"id":x.id,"name":x.name,"description":x.description}
    #the +1 to start keys at 1 as in your example, instead of 0
```

**Edit:** Actually, after re-reading your example, it sounds like you want the ID to be the key in the dictionary, not just numbered arbitrarily from 1-n...

In that case, as long as you're sure there's no duplicate IDs (dict keys must be unique) :

```
the_dict={}
for x in Test.objects.filter(act=True):
    the_dict[str(x.id)]={"id":x.id,"name":x.name,"description":x.description}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, there are no lists. There is a dictionary with nested dictionaries. Try...

```
data = {}
for x in Test.objects.filter(act=True):
    data["%s" % x.id] = {"id":"%s" % x.id, "name": "%s" % x.name, "description": "%s" % x.description}

ins = {}
ins['instance'] = data
```

or

```
data = {}
for x in Test.objects.filter(act=True):
    data[str(x.id)] = {"id":str(x.id), "name": str(x.name), "description": str(x.description)}

ins = {}
ins['instance'] = data
```